# Converting dbo file from windows to linux

Tags: mysql, windows, linux

I have a .dbo file which is created from windows. This file is succesfully reloaded into the mysql database in windows. I need to reload the dbo file into the mysql/mariadb database in linux. How I convert the file that was created from windows to linux?

Answer (score 1):

You said you have reloaded the file into a MySQL database. 
A simple way is:

1. use `mysqldump` to backup the the data into a file
2. transfer the file to the linux system
3. use command `source filename.sql` to load the data into the MySQL database on the linux server.